# How can I apply different aggregate functions to different columns in R?

Tags: r, plyr, data.table

How can I apply different aggregate functions to different columns in R? The `aggregate()` function only offers one function argument to be passed:

```
V1  V2        V3
1   18.45022  62.24411694
2   90.34637  20.86505214
1   50.77358  27.30074987
2   52.95872  30.26189013
1   61.36935  26.90993530
2   49.31730  70.60387016
1   43.64142  87.64433517
2   36.19730  83.47232907
1   91.51753  0.03056485
... ...       ...

> aggregate(sample,by=sample["V1"],FUN=sum)
  V1 V1       V2       V3
1  1 10 578.5299 489.5307
2  2 20 575.2294 527.2222
```

How can I apply a *different* function to each column, i.e. aggregate `V2` with the `mean()` function and `V2` with the `sum()` function, without calling `aggregate()` multiple times?

Comment: @mdsumner any other function with any other beautiful name is appreciated as well of course

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For that task, I will use `ddply` in `plyr`

```
> library(plyr)
> ddply(sample, .(V1), summarize, V2 = sum(V2), V3 = mean(V3))
  V1       V2       V3
1  1 578.5299 48.95307
2  2 575.2294 52.72222
```

Comment: I really like plyr's simplicity. Started using it after I learned about this package here on stackoverflow.

Comment: That's nice! Whats the magic with the "summarize" argument here? EDIT: got that, thats the actual function applied with additional arguments passed later on.

Answer (score 5):

...Or the function `data.table` in the package of the same name:

```
library(data.table)

myDT <- data.table(sample) # As mdsumner suggested, this is not a great name

myDT[, list(sumV2 = sum(V2), meanV3 = mean(V3)), by = V1]

#      V1    sumV2   meanV3
# [1,]  1 578.5299 48.95307
# [2,]  2 575.2294 52.72222
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the dataframe `x` rather than `sample` which is already taken.

EDIT:

The `by` function provides a more direct route than split/apply/combine

```
by(x, list(x$V1), f)
```

:EDIT

```
lapply(split(x, x$V1), myfunkyfunctionthatdoesadifferentthingforeachcolumn)
```

Of course, that's not a separate function for each column but one can do both jobs.

```
myfunkyfunctionthatdoesadifferentthingforeachcolumn = function(x) c(sum(x$V2), mean(x$V3))
```

Convenient ways to collate the result are possible such as this (but check out plyr package for a comprehensive solution, consider this motivation to learn something better).

```
 matrix(unlist(lapply(split(x, x$V1), myfunkyfunctionthatdoesadifferentthingforeachcolumn)), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(unique(x$V1), c("sum", "mean")))
```

Comment: Nice to know! I do prefer to get around that extra work of implementing the intermediate function though, thus the package that kohske suggested does exactly what I was looking for :)