# How to aggregate data in data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a large data.frame. The data.frame include a lot of values.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(Company = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'), 
                 Name = c("Wayne", "Duane", "William", "Rafael", "John", "Eric", "James", "Pablo", "Tammy"), 
                 Age = c(26, 27, 28, 32, 28, 24, 34, 30, 25), 
                 Wages = c(50000, 70000, 70000, 60000, 50000, 70000, 65000, 50000, 50000), 
                 Education.University = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), 
                 Productivity = c(100, 120, 120, 95, 88, 115, 100, 90, 120))
```

How can I aggregate my `data.frame`? I want to analyze values on every Company. It must look like:

[image]

Age -> average Age of all employees in Company

Wages -> average Wages of all employees in Company

Education.University -> sum of factors (1 or 0) for all employees in Company

Productivity -> average Productivity of all employees in Company

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I apply different aggregate functions to different columns in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702708/how-can-i-apply-different-aggregate-functions-to-different-columns-in-r)

Answer (score 9):

Base R

```
cbind(aggregate(.~Company, df[,-c(2, 5)], mean),
      aggregate(Education.University~Company, df, sum)[-1])
#  Company      Age    Wages Productivity Education.University
#1       A 27.00000 56666.67     102.6667                    2
#2       B 28.66667 68333.33     111.6667                    3
#3       C 29.00000 53333.33     101.6667                    1
```

Here is the longer version that may be easier to understand

```
merge(x = aggregate(x = list(Age_av = df$Age,
                             Wages_av = df$Wages,
                             Productivity_av = df$Productivity),
                by = list(Company = df$Company),
                FUN = mean),
      y = aggregate(x = list(Education.University_sum = df$Education.University),
                by = list(Company = df$Company),
                FUN = sum),
      by = "Company")
#  Company   Age_av Wages_av Productivity_av Education.University_sum
#1       A 27.00000 56666.67        102.6667                        2
#2       B 28.66667 68333.33        111.6667                        3
#3       C 29.00000 53333.33        101.6667                        1
```

Answer (score 4):

One option is using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c(lapply(.SD[, c(2:3, 5), with = FALSE], mean), 
    .(Education.University = sum(Education.University))), by = Company]
#   Company      Age    Wages Productivity Education.University
#1:       A 27.00000 56666.67     102.6667                    2
#2:       B 28.66667 68333.33     111.6667                    3
#3:       C 29.00000 53333.33     101.6667                    1
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Company) %>% 
   mutate(Education.University = sum(Education.University)) %>%
   summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  Company      Age    Wages Education.University Productivity
#   <fctr>    <dbl>    <dbl>                <dbl>        <dbl>
#1       A 27.00000 56666.67                    2     102.6667
#2       B 28.66667 68333.33                    3     111.6667
#3       C 29.00000 53333.33                    1     101.6667
```

Comment: @akrun thank you! data.table works. is it possible in `dplyr` group_by more values, for example, `Company` and `Name`?

Comment: @Denis  Yes, you can use `group_by(Company, Name)`

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do it by using *dplyr* library.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Company) %>% summarise(Age = mean(Age), Wages = mean(Wages), Education.University = sum(Education.University), Productivity = mean(Productivity))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the "aggregate" function

```
aggregate(x = df[c("Age","Wages","Education.University","Productivity")], by = df[c("Company")], FUN = mean)

#  Company      Age    Wages Education.University Productivity
#1       A 27.00000 56666.67            0.6666667     102.6667
#2       B 28.66667 68333.33            1.0000000     111.6667
#3       C 29.00000 53333.33            0.3333333     101.6667
```

Comment: OP requires sum for education university and averages for the rest.

Comment: @Brutalroot If I wanted add multiple statistics at once could I do that?  I want to get mean,min,max, sd, Iqr, Mscore and a few others ignoring NA and make a new df for each statistics

Comment: @user3614197 check this toppic.

'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064202/apply-several-summary-functions-on-several-variables-by-group-in-one-call'

Answer (score 2):

The concise `data.table` solution already [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45700055/3817004) is using column *numbers* instead of column *names*. This is considered *bad practice* according to
[Frequently Asked Questions about data.table, section 1.1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#j-num):

> If your colleague comes along and reads your code later they may have to hunt around to find out which column is number 5. If you or they change the column ordering higher up in your R program, you may produce wrong results with no warning or error if you forget to change all the places in your code which refer to column number 5.

So, I would like to propose alternative approaches which use column names.

#### Variant 1

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(average.Age = mean(Age), 
              average.Wages = mean(Wages), 
              sum.Education.University = sum(Education.University),
              average.Productivity = mean(Productivity)), 
          by = Company]
```

> ```
>    Company average.Age average.Wages sum.Education.University average.Productivity
> 1:       A    27.00000      56666.67                        2             102.6667
> 2:       B    28.66667      68333.33                        3             111.6667
> 3:       C    29.00000      53333.33                        1             101.6667
> ```

Here, every column is aggregated separately. Although it requires more of typing, it has several benefits:

1. It is easy to understand what the code snippet is intended to do.
2. The column names in the result can be amended as required.
3. The order of columns in the result can be controlled if required.

#### Variant 2

If there are many columns which require the same operations, the `data.table` FAQ [recommends](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#how-can-i-avoid-writing-a-really-long-j-expression-youve-said-that-i-should-use-the-column-names-but-ive-got-a-lot-of-columns.) to use `.SDcols`. So, we can do

```
m_cols <- c("Age", "Wages", "Productivity")
s_cols <- c("Education.University")
by_cols <- c("Company") 
setDT(df)[, c(.SD[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = m_cols],
              .SD[, lapply(.SD, sum ), .SDcols = s_cols]),
          by = by_cols]
```

> ```
>    Company      Age    Wages Productivity Education.University
> 1:       A 27.00000 56666.67     102.6667                    2
> 2:       B 28.66667 68333.33     111.6667                    3
> 3:       C 29.00000 53333.33     101.6667                    1
> ```

This is similar to [Akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45700055/3817004) but uses column *names* instead of column *numbers*. In addition, the column names are stored in a variable which is handy for programming.

Note that `by_cols` may contain additional columns for aggregation, .e.g,

```
by_cols <- c("Company", "Name")
```

If column order matters, we can use `setcolorder()`:

```
result <- setDT(df)[, c(.SD[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = m_cols],
                        .SD[, lapply(.SD, sum ), .SDcols = s_cols]),
                    by = by_cols]
setcolorder(result, intersect(names(df), names(result)))
result
```

> ```
>    Company      Age    Wages Education.University Productivity
> 1:       A 27.00000 56666.67                    2     102.6667
> 2:       B 28.66667 68333.33                    3     111.6667
> 3:       C 29.00000 53333.33                    1     101.6667
> ```

Likewise, the column names of the result can be amended to meet OP's requirements:

```
setnames(result, m_cols, paste0("average.", m_cols))
setnames(result, s_cols, paste0("sum.", s_cols))
result
```

> ```
>    Company average.Age average.Wages sum.Education.University average.Productivity
> 1:       A    27.00000      56666.67                        2             102.6667
> 2:       B    28.66667      68333.33                        3             111.6667
> 3:       C    29.00000      53333.33                        1             101.6667
> ```

Note that the `data.table` functions `setcolorder()` and `setnames()` work *in place*, i.e., without copying the `data.table` object. This saves memory and time which is of particular importantance when dealing with large tables.